# qmlRegisterType in main behave wierd

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qabstractitemmodel

I implemented a model in c++ and want to assign to Qml, but the error message showed that:

> Unable to assign a function to a property of any type other than var.

What might be the problem with my code, thanks!

**.qml**

```
ListView{
        anchors.fill: parent
        model:MyModel{
            list:data
        }
        delegate: objRecursiveDelegate
    }
```

**main.cpp**

```
qmlRegisterType<MyModel>("Model",1,0,"MyModel");
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Data>("Model",1,0,"Data",QStringLiteral("Data should not be created in QML"));

Data data;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("data"), &data);
```

> MyModel.h(try to define using QAbstractListModel)

```
class Data;
class MyModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Data *list READ list WRITE setList)

    public:
        Data *list() const;
        void setList(Data *list);
    private:
        Data* mList;
 }
```

> MyModel.cpp

```
Data *MyModel::list() const
{
    return mList;
}
 void MyModel::setList(Data *list)
{
    beginResetModel();
    if (mList)
        mList->disconnect(this);
    mList = list;
    /..../
    endResetModel();
}
```

> data.h

```
class Data:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Data(QObject *parent = nullptr);
 /..../
private:
    QVector<unit> menu;
};
```

Comment: I recommend you do not use `list` name, it is a reserved word in QML: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html

Comment: How should I change my code, can you briefly explain?

Comment: I need all the necessary code to reproduce your error, we call that [mcve] :)

Comment: Is this information sufficient enough?

Comment: Think that with that code I can reproduce your problem, why can not you share the necessary code?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have been checking what is necessary, and it took some time. Is this proper now?

Comment: I do not understand your secrecy, I just want to copy, paste and test your code, I do not want to waste time patching code, if you save me time indirectly it will also save you. Show the complete code please.

Comment: @eyllanesc May I have your email to give you a complete version of my code?Since too much code is prohibit from this website, thanks!

Comment: Upload it to github, drive, dropbox, etc and share the link. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc https://github.com/Berry1997/Qt_menu thanks!

Comment: please let me know if you have reached the project

Comment: see my answer..

Comment: @eyllanesc `list` is not a reserved word in qml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is really simple, the `data()` method of QAbstractListModel, so if you use data inside `MyModel` it is interpreting that you want to use this method and not the data that you really want to pass, the solution is to change the name:

***.cpp**

```
Data data;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("info"), &data);
```

***.qml**

```
ListView{
    anchors.fill: parent
    model:MyModel{
        list: info
    }
    delegate: objRecursiveDelegate
}
```

Plus:

- On the other hand you have another error, the Data items method must return menu:

  ```
  QVector<unit> Data::items() const{
      return menu;
  }
  ```
- On the other hand in your delegate you must access access to each role using the name if the model:

  ```
  Component {
      id: objRecursiveDelegate
      Column {
          Row {
              //indent
              Item {
                  height: 1
                  width: level * 40 // <--
              }
              Text {
                  text: name // <--
              }
              Button{
                  x:550
                  width:30
                  text: "-"
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I have made other improvements to your code so you can find the complete code in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51034391-Qt_menu-master).

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if I wish to append items when clicked the button "ADDtitle", How should I pass the parameters into appendItem function?

Comment: @Changlin already update the repository with that functionality, check how it should be done, on the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it review the [tour], it is the best way to thank.

Comment: I have marked it correct! Another little problem is that if I wish to append something into the subNode array, why won't it work by calling menu.at(i).subNodes.append(item) in appendItem function?

Comment: @Changlin Analyze it, now I'm not with my PC so I can not help for today, tomorrow maybe

Comment: just to make sure, calling append method is the right way?

Comment: @Changlin I do not understand what you want to do. Why did you create the Data class? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to create a two level menu, which the subNode will include all the level2 items under that level1 item, thats why I want to append items inside the subNode.

Comment: @Changlin 
and why do you use a QAbstractListModel and not a QAbstractItemModel? since your model is tree type

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new to Qt, and I am not clear about the difference.

Comment: @Changlin 
In a tree-type model there is already the dependence of parents and children, I recommend reading http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html. I think you are trying to run if you still do not know how to crawl, at all times you will have problems as simple as this that could bore us, I think you understand me, learn the basics and then try the complex.